# Regex for validate a number with some criteria

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate a number with those criterias :

1. Can be float or integer
2. Scale 4
3. Precision 2

I tried like this :

```
pattern="/^[-+]?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/i",
```

Some examples :

1. valid : 2; -1; 0.4; 0.12; 1928; 1827.78; -182.4
2. invalid : 10000; 0.345; 89374.5;

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'/^[-+]?(?:[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7NNt56/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[-+]?` - either `-` or `+`
- `(?:[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `[1-9]\d{0,3}` - a digit from `1` to `9` (non-zero) and any 0 to 3 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `0`  - a zero
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.